# What is a real-life situation where injected currents can impact a home appliance?

Tags: emc

I am refreshing my study on EMC testing guidelines and I am reading a reference guide that mentions,

> the typical use of BCI (bulk current injection) is to inject a common-mode current into a cable or cable bundle to simulate an illuminating RF field.

What do they mean by an illuminated RF field and what might be a real-life situation that can create this "illuminated RF field"?

Comment: illuminatING not illuminatED. They mean an RF field that "lights up" the relevant cable, which then interferes (or not) with the connected equipment. Like the old GSM phones that made buzzing noises on my clock radio.

Comment: So this RF field can be created by another device that is connected to the same voltage source, perhaps?  Or perhaps a device with a motor that is running near to the appliance under question?

Comment: It can be connected to any voltage source or its own battery.

Comment: for example, an illuminating RF field is used to power up an RFID tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What do they mean by an illuminated RF field*

You've misquoted your quote; the word is `illuminating`.

In this context, the word `illuminating` is a bit poetic and means the same as this: -

A `prevailing RF field` or `an incident RF field`.

In other words an RF field applied directly or close to your cable.

> *what might be a real-life situation that can create this "illuminated
> RF field"?*

Again, the word is `illuminating` - we like accuracy of terminology in EE.

A real-life situation can be injecting a cable with an RF pulse from what is know as an "injector": -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.batterfly.com/shop/pl/a-capacitively-coupled-pin-injection-method-zhang). This one happens to be a capacitive injector but, inductive injectors can also be used (depending on the tests you are trying to perform).

Here's another common type: -

[image]

You lay the cable in the slot, close the lid and use the external terminals for the RF interfering pulse or waveform. Image from [the EMC shop](https://www.theemcshop.com/em-injection-clamps/945-schloder-cdn-emcl-35-current-injection-clamp-for-rf-conducted-immunity-testing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  So, if I am testing a home appliance and it fails the BCI test; then what exactly are we protecting the appliance against?  In other words, if I have a toaster on a kitchen counter, what may cause an injection of an RF pulse which could disrupt the operation of the toaster?

Comment: The most likely type of problem is from indirect lightning surges, Anything up to a couple of thousand amp surge can be encountered depending on how the manufacturer of the toaster decides to design the device. Certainly pulses of several hundred amps can occur (lower rating of EN61000-4-5. Usually, a toaster will survive unless it's got some particularly poorly designed electronic timing circuits. These types of pulse have rise times of about 1 microsecond and, therefore, do actually fall under the general umbrella of RF.

Comment: @Gary any kind of nearby radio transmitter.